# i have a problem with JS function that doesn't change html class

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm new with JS and html, So please go easy on me.
I made a registration form that contains multiple steps.
I have two button in two different form. next form button and back button. next button works perfectly and it changes html id base on what I needed. but the back button which is exactly like previous one doesn't work. Why?

I want that JS functions changes html class.

```js
function backPageFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".containerform1").id = 'containerform1';
  document.querySelector(".containerform2").id = 'containerform2'
  document.getElementById('progress-step1').style.width = '250px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col2').style.fontSize = '15px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col1').style.fontSize = '18px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col1').style.color = '#f0eaea';
  document.querySelector('.step-col2').style.color = '#546E7A';
};

function nextPageFunction() {
  // containerform1.id='secActive1';
  document.querySelector(".containerform1").id = 'secActive1';
  document.querySelector(".containerform2").id = 'secActive2';
  // containerform2.id='secActive2';
  document.getElementById('progress-step1').style.width = '470px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col1').style.fontSize = '15px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col2').style.fontSize = '18px';
  document.querySelector('.step-col2').style.color = '#f0eaea';
  document.querySelector('.step-col1').style.color = '#546E7A';

};
```

```css
#secActive1 {
  width: 982px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cfd8dc;
  background: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 1s;
}

#secActive2 {
  width: 982px;
  height: 270px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cfd8dc;
  background: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: 1s;
}

#containerform1 {
  width: 982px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cfd8dc;
  background: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

#containerform2 {
  width: 982px;
  height: 270px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cfd8dc;
  background: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-btn-box">
  <button class="nextbtnform1" id="nextbtnform1" onclick="nextPageFunction()">ثبت اطلاعات و ادامه  </button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div id="containerform2" class="containerform2">
  <form id="Form2" class="Form2">
    <fieldset id="Form2">
      <legend class="form-title">مشخصات حرفه‌ای و شغلی</legend>
      <div class="form_row three_column clearfix">
        <div>
          <label>سطح تحصیلات</label>
          <span class="star">*</span>
          <select id="edu" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty" name="edu" valid-directive="isEmpty">
            <option label="دیپلم و پایینتر" value="number:100" selected="selected">دیپلم و پایینتر</option>
            <option label="فوق دیپلم" value="number:101">فوق دیپلم</option>
            <option label="کارشناسی" value="number:102">کارشناسی</option>
            <option label="کارشناسی ارشد" value="number:103">کارشناسی ارشد</option>
            <option label="دکتری و بالاتر" value="number:104">دکتری و بالاتر</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>رشته تحصیلی</label>
          <span class="star">*</span>
          <input id="degree">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>دانشگاه محل تحصیل</label>
          <span class="star">*</span>
          <input id="college" name="college" valid-directive="isEmpty,isPersianAlphaWithoutNumber,isInAlphabet([2#50])">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="clearfix moshakhasat_canoon ng-scope">
      <div class="next-btn-box">
        <button class="backbtnform2" id="backbtnform2" onclick='backPageFunction()'>بازگشت و ویرایش اطلاعات</button>
```

Comment: Seems it's missing part of your html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi so I you want to change classes of elements try this:

**1)** Change `id`'s to `classes` in `css`:

like `.secActive1,` .`secActive2` etc.

**2)** JS:

```
function changeClasses(){ 
    document.querySelector(".containerform1").classList.add('secActive1'); 
    document.querySelector(".containerform1").classList.add('secActive2'); 
}
```

Don't forget to remove them when other button is clicked:

```
function changeClassesBack(){
   document.querySelector(".containerform1").classList.remove('secActive1');
   document.querySelector(".containerform1").classList.remove('secActive2');
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for  your answer. i did what you told and the code is cleaner now but still after clicking on button it reload the entire page. I find out that adding type="button" solve the problem. its funny beacuse the first button doesn't have that and it works just fine. thank you agian.